# Need business web hosting, with INSTANT activation and DECENT support

Tags: cloud, hosting, vps, shared

Trying to open a web hosting account, for a business project. Budget is up to $ 40-50 per month.

Tried Codero - RIDICULOUS delays with server start, took Support 2.5 hours just to get the server up and running. I'm not talking website, I'm talking just to have a functioning server to work on.

Tried HostGator - promises "instant" account setup, actually needs to be "approved". Hold time: 19 minutes for chat, 15 minutes on the phone. Hung up, created a ticket to cancel.

Tried InMotion Hosting - same issue with support, plus deceptive billing (advertised as $ 9.99/month, it's ACTUALLY $ 19.99/month, plus $ 40.00 setup). Nope.

Tried Google Cloud - waaay too complicated + no Plesk/WHM. I'm not spending a month learning how to do everything through SSH, sorry.

And so on.

So, here's the question:

Where can I get hosting that:

- Has a Plesk / WHM control panel.
- Has an ACTUALLY INSTANT account activation, with no BS "approval" process.
- Has a tech support that actually responds, AND knows what they're doing.
- Is headquartered in the US.

Any suggestions would be MUCH appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

check out http://blackcows.net/dedi.html

activation should be within few hours.

they can install plesk/cpanel and whm

talk to their support for your exact configuration you need and they will set you up with a decent priced server.

They offer personalized support.